# Disable/overwrite all nice looking css effects to speed up the application?

Tags: css, cordova

I am building an application for mobile phone which I will convert from my web-based application. I have already made the application, but when I run the app on the phone the application is slow. I have figured out that it is because all of the "fancy" things that css and foundation has.

Is there someone who have an CSS property that would overwrite all of the "fancy" CSS effects like shadows,gradient backgrounds etc. in one of few properties that would overwrite usage of all those usages?

Comment: use @media queries to adjust the settings based on mobile use vs web use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such css property. Maybe you should create separate mobile.css and reset all stuff there. Or adjust some of [existing](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) reset css rules to your needs.

Comment: yes, something like that you have referenced in the link, but if it would be something for visual effects, that would I think do the trick